# Using a Makefile to get latest git tag

Tags: git, makefile, docker

I have a Makefile which I use to build my docker image.

```
NAME = demo/docker-test

default: build

build:
    docker build -t $(NAME) .

push:
    docker push $(NAME)
```

I would like to append to the `build` the latest version from my Git tags i.e.

```
build:
    docker build -t $(NAME):$(VERSION) .
```

So if I have 3 tags in Git `v.1.2`, `v.1.3`, `v.1.4` VERSION would be `v.1.4`.

Is this possible in a Makefile? If so how, where do I start?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
git describe --tags
```

Should give you the output needed

From there you should be able to check out the files in the make script

Comment: cool did not think of that. So this works a little better: ``git describe --abbrev=0 --tags``